# Change "MacOS" to "OS X" in the help center

Tags: bug, status-completed

I was reading through the [On-Topic page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of your help center and noticed this line:

> - The Unix foundation underlying MacOS (but generally not frontend application questions)

Which was what I was looking for and answered my question about scope. **But**, it's kinda inaccurate. The OS name is no longer MacOS (hasn't been for ages), and [Mac OS X was phased out two years ago](http://www.theverge.com/2012/2/16/2802281/apple-officially-renames-mac-os-x-to-os-x-drops-the-mac) - meaning the correct name is now "OS X".

Could the help center be edited to reflect this?

Comment: The name changed back to macOS again in 2016, this time with a lower case M.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed.

> - The Unix foundation underlying OS X (but generally not frontend application questions)