# Alias macOS to OS X?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

There are two similar tags [macos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos) and [osx](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx), and it's confusing which to use.

Would be a good idea to make them synonyms?

Comment: Linking in some historical related posts: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2816/117549 and https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15/117549

Comment: Actually, `/macos` and `/osx` should be synonyms for `darwin` under the definitions on the On Topic page.

Comment: fd0: I see what you mean, but at the same time it is possible to run Darwin without the whole normal OS X userland... E.g., puredarwin, or in the old days opendarwin. These would have a "normal" X server (xorg) and a much more traditional Unix-y feel, since they lack the OS X secret sauce (like cocoa). Heck, you might even be able to install CDE on them and have it work properly. I don't think 'darwin' really is 100% the same as OS X/Mac OS from a pedantic standpoint.

Answer (score 31):

These should be synonyms, but [macos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos), being the currently preferred name of the OS, should be the master, and the other tags synonyms of it. That doesn't match the current suggestion.

Comment: Yes, `macos` should be the main tag, the other's should be synonyms for that tag.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, I think they should be synonyms; I’ve added a candidate on the [osx](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx) [synonyms page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/osx/synonyms), feel free to vote it up or down.

Answer (score -2):

Use darwin, macos-classic, macosx/macos-x/osx. I would prefer macos-x.

Comment: Is macos-classic really a 'unix', though? I mean, maybe if you're using A/UX...

Comment: No, in fact, macOS classic is not a Unix.  It has no familial relationship to Unix, few or none of the Unix user interfaces, and little or none of the Unix API.