# Change macos/osx tag synonym

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Currently the [macos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos) tag is a synonym of [osx](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx),  however OS X ended in 2015 and Apple's operating system has been called macOS since.  I think the tags should be reversed so that [osx](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx) is a synonym for [macos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos) rather than the opposite.

Comment: Yes! It's a pity this was not done last year when the synonym was created. https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4844/alias-macos-to-os-x

Comment: Yes, I messed up there. I think only mods can flip a synonym around.

Comment: Is there a consensus that last years modifications involving these tags got the synonyms reversed?

Comment: @Kusalananda, well the votes on the answers to that last meta question seem to favor [tag:macos] being the main tag, and well, rightly so.

Comment: I have now swapped the tags so that [tag:osx] is a synonym for [tag:macos].