# Compton to Picom Retag

Tags: discussion, tags

The most actively developed fork of Compton (used by most distros) has been renamed Picom.

https://github.com/yshui/picom/issues/222

Should we adjust the tags ([compton](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compton)) accordingly or at least add a Picom tag to most Compton questions as they'll be relevant?

Comment: A synonym might make sense here -- then users can find the topic using either name. I don't know if there would be confusion around the old name...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the same pattern as what we ended up doing for macOS ([Change macos/osx tag synonym](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5445/86440)), I think the best approach should result in [picom](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/picom) as the main tag and [compton](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compton) as a synonym. As I understand it, these would be the steps involved (without moderator intervention):

- add a [picom](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/picom) to existing [compton](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compton) questions;
- make sure any relevant information from the [compton](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compton) tag wiki is copied to the [picom](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/picom) tag wiki;
- suggest [compton](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compton) as a synonym of [picom](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/picom).

Comment: Sounds like a plan, I've not got the rep to make a new tag though

Comment: I’ve created it for you.